# CRUD Operations in HQL using Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hql, apache-spark-sql

I am trying perform **CRUD** operations in **HQL** using **Apache Spark.** **Select** and **Insert** Statements working well while **update** and **delete** and getting exceptions in **java**.

here is my **select** and **insert** statements:

**Select**:
select * from employee;

**Insert:**
insert into employee select t.* from(select 1,'hadoop','hyderabad')t;

For **insert** i am using temp table for execution. Is there any way to execute **update** and **delete** statements?

I am using **Spark 1.6.2** and **hive 1.2.1**

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL supports only a subset of HQL which can be used for batch job and is not a generic Hive interface. Updates and deletes are not supported.

If you need this you should use external Hive client directly.